# JSON request 400 response: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

Tags: java, json

We have such object:

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@Document(collection = Order.COLLECTION_NAME)
public class Order implements Serializable {
public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "orders";

@Id
private Long id;
private Long orgId;
private Long userId;
private Date creationDate = new Date();
private Integer statusCode = Status.NEW.code();
private Integer typeCode;
private Integer paymentCode;
private Date date;
private String phoneNumber;
private List<UserAddressList> userAddressList;
private BigDecimal cash;
private Integer persons;
private String comments;
private List products;

@Indexed(unique = true)
private String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

private Boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;
```

In this object we have two Lists which contains 2 another objects:

```
private List userAddressList;  
private List products;

public class UserAddressList implements Serializable {

private String street;
private String house;
private String building;
private Long flat;
private Long entrance;
private Long floor;
private String intercom;


public class ProductPack implements Serializable {
private Long productId;
private Integer quantity;

public ProductPack() {
}

public ProductPack(Long productId, Integer quantity) {
    this.productId = productId;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

We have such api method for adding new order:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseDto addOrder(
     @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authorization,
     @RequestBody final Order order) {
```

When we send this JSON to the server:

```
{"statusCode": 0,  
 "typeCode": 1,  
 "paymentCode": 4,  
 "date": 2430919020590,  
 "phoneNumber": "+79216450091",  
 "userAddressList":  
 [{  
 "street": "Test",  
 "house": "House",  
 "building": "A",  
 "entrance": 1,  
 "floor": 8,  
 "intercom": "intercom",  
 "flat": 12  
 }]  
 ,  
 "persons": 1,  
 "products":   
 [{  
 "productId": 97,  
 "quantity": 5  
 }  
 ]}
```

it returns "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

when we send this JSON:

```
{"statusCode": 0,  
"typeCode": 1,  
"paymentCode": 4,  
"date": 2430919020590,  
"phoneNumber": "+79216450091",  
"persons": 1,  
"products": [  
{  
"productId": 97,  
"quantity": 5  
}  
]}
```

server accepts it but userAddressList is null

Can you please help to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check conformity between your fields in the JSON-request and in the code. It is possible that field you have declared is not that field that servers maps. For example *UserAddressList* could be *address*.